# Is it possible to use onError to restart a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've got a carousel on my search app. I've set it up with a for loop that maxes out at 11 iterations. The loop is iterating over a lot of subfolders within a directory, and the path is set up dynamically. That's in order to get as many images as I can in the carousel.

The number of images varies within each subfolder. Some have none, others have upwards of 30. The majority of them top out at 4 or 5 images, which means that there'll be around 6 or 7 broken images in the carousel.

My question is this: is it possible to use `onError` to restart the loop, thus making a sort of hacky infinity-type slider? I know you can just set a default image, but as far as I can tell, that's only one and it's static.

EDIT: This is my code. I'm using the [React Image Gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery):

```
  let images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      images.push({
        original: `${PREFIX_URL}${i}.jpg`,
        thumbnail:`${PREFIX_URL}${i}.jpg`
      });
    }

  <ImageGallery 
     items={images}
     lazyLoad={true}
   />
```

Comment: Can you remove the image path from array (which should be in state) on onError, and if the carousal is linked to state, this should work

Comment: @kiranjv I've updated my OP with the snippet, if the context helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle onError for  like this:

```
getInitialState: function(event) {
  return {errored: true};
},

handleError: function(event) {
  this.setState({errored: true});
},

render: function() {
  if (this.state.errored) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return <img onError={this.handleError} src={src} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my OP with the code I'm using. I'll play around with your suggestion, though.

Comment: "A code snippet would have helped" belongs into a comment rather than into an answer. However, how does that answer the question? This is not restarting the looping through the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested)

```
constructor() {
  super();


let images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      images.push({
        original: `${PREFIX_URL}${i}.jpg`,
        thumbnail:`${PREFIX_URL}${i}.jpg`
      });
    }

  this.state = {
    images: images
  }

  this.handleImageError = this.handleImageError.bind(this);
}
```

**In render**

```
  <ImageGallery 
     ref={i => this._imageGallery = i}
     items={this.state.images}
     lazyLoad={true}
     onImageError = {this.handleImageError}
   />
```

**handleImageError**

```
handleImageError(event) {

 let index = this._imageGallery.getCurrentIndex();
 this.setState({
    data: this.state.images.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
  });

}
```

Comment: It throws an error at me, saying "images" is not defined in render.

Comment: Some info I didn't put in the OP: I'm also using the starter app for SearchKit, which is based on the starter app for React. The way the app came, there isn't a good way to put a constructor. I suppose what I'm looking for is doing what you've done, just without the constructor. I'm messing around with that now.